# Can't fetch RDF files JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an RDF file from a URL using `fetch()` but I it doesn't seem to work through code. If I enter the URL directly in a web browser, it'll download the file.

Let's say this is the RDF file I want to download: http://www.regmurcia.com/eventos.rdf

Here is my code:

```
fetch("http://www.regmurcia.com/eventos.rdf", {'mode': 'no-cors'})
        .then(res => {
            return res.text()
        })
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res)
        })
    }
```

This will log an empty string in the console. I tried using blob() and the result was empty too.

When I try to fetch other types of data (json, xml, etc..) it works.

Any idea why this isn't working ?

Comment: Have you tried without `no-cors`?

Comment: I did but it did'nt work in the environment I work in without no-cors.